# Extract data from multiple sheets into one sheet using array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to extract data from multiple source sheets to a destination sheet(OUTPUT). By using array I want to get all the data that have met the given conditions, but the code is not working.

It overwrites the previous outputs and Only outputs the last one.
I want to keep all the output data from all sheets.

```
Sub Extractdata()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT")
    Dim data As Variant
    data = ws.Range("B8").CurrentRegion.Value
    
    Dim rowCount As Long, columnCount As Long
    rowCount = UBound(data, 1)
    columnCount = UBound(data, 2)
    
    Dim destRow As Long
    destRow = 7
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim arrData As Variant
    ReDim arrData(8 To lastRow, 2 To 17)
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA1" Or ws.Name = "DATA02" Or ws.Name = "DATA03" Then
            For i = 8 To lastRow
                If (Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) And ws.Cells(i, "F").Value <> "1") And _
                   (ws.Cells(i, "N").Value <= todayData) Then
                    For j = 2 To 17
                        arrData(i, j) = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
                    Next j
                    wsDest.Range("B7").Resize(rowCount, columnCount) = arrData
                    destRow = destRow + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't declared `lastRow`. `Next ws` is missing. If `todayData` is supposed to be today's date, simply use `Date` instead.

Comment: Put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement

Answer (score 3):

### Copy Data From Multiple Worksheets

**Source (`Data01`)**

[image]

**Destination (`Output`)**

[image]

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
Sub ExtractData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "B8"
    Dim sSheetNames As Variant:
    sSheetNames = Array("Data01", "Data02", "Data03")
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B7"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Output"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, Data As Variant, IsRowValid As Long
    Dim sn As Long, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long, cCount As Long
    
    ' Loop.
    For sn = LBound(sSheetNames) To UBound(sSheetNames)
        ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet.
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if the worksheet doesn't exist
            Set sws = wb.Sheets(sSheetNames(sn))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            ' Reference the source range.
            Set srg = RefCurrentRegion(sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL))
            ' Return the values from the source range in a 2D one-based array.
            Data = GetRange(srg)
            cCount = UBound(Data, 2) ' number of columns
            ' Copy the rows that meet the requirement to the top of the array.
            For sr = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
                If IsToBeCopied(Data, sr) Then ' meets the requirement
                    dr = dr + 1
                    For c = 1 To cCount
                        Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                    Next c
                'Else ' doesn't meet the requirement; do nothing
                End If
            Next sr
            If dr > 0 Then ' rows that meet the requirement found
                ' Copy to required values from the top of the array
                ' to the destination range.
                dcell.Resize(dr, cCount).Value = Data
                Set dcell = dcell.Offset(dr) ' set for the next iteration
                dr = 0 ' reset for the next iteration
            'Else ' no rows that meet the requirement found; do nothing
            End If
            Set sws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist; do nothing
        End If
    Next sn

    MsgBox "Data extracted.", vbInformation
  
End Sub
```

**The Called (Helper) Procedures**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      References the range from a given cell to the last cell
'               of the given cell's Current Region.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCurrentRegion(firstCell As Range) As Range
    With firstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = firstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - firstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - firstCell.Column)
    End With
End Function
```

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange(rg As Range) As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      ... checks if a row is to be copied...
' Remarks:      Only useful for this code.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsToBeCopied(Data As Variant, sr As Long) As Boolean
    If Not IsEmpty(Data(sr, 1)) Then ' 'B'
        If CStr(Data(sr, 5)) <> "1" Then ' 'F'
            If IsDate(Data(sr, 13)) Then ' 'N'
                If Data(sr, 13) <= Date Then IsToBeCopied = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

destRow is the running counter of the destination row to write.

destlastrow is the pointer to the first free row on OUTPUT sheet.

Range(Bx:Qx) are copied to the target sheet.

```
Sub Extractdata()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OUTPUT")
    Dim data As Variant
    
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim destlastrow As Long
    destlastrow = 7
    destRow = 7
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA1" Or ws.Name = "DATA02" Or ws.Name = "DATA03" Then
            lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row   'moved here
            destRow = destlastrow
           For i = 8 To lastrow
                If (Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "B").Value) And ws.Cells(i, "F").Value <> "1") And _
                   (ws.Cells(i, "N").Value <= todayData) Then
                     wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(destRow, 2), wsDest.Cells(destRow, 17)).Value = ws.Range("B" & i & ":Q" & i).Value
                    destRow = destRow + 1
                End If
            Next i
            destlastrow = destRow
        End If
    Next ws
    End Sub
```